# Kinect (XBoxOne) SDK 2.0 - Depth Sensor Blind Spot (Sensor Misaligned?)

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a black region on the right-hand side of the depth frame. 
When I point the Kinect at a white wall, I get the following (see attached picture from Kinect Studio): the black region never goes away.

Depth Frame:
[image: kinect studio depth image]

IR Frame:
[image] SDK2.

It doesn't seem to matter where I point the Kinect or how the lighting situation is; the result is always the same.

I supsect the Depth Sensor/IR Emitter to be somehow misaligned. 
Does anybody know if I can align or calibrate the Sensors somehow? Or is it a hardware issue?

Using Kinect for XBox One with the Kinect For Windows USB Adapter.

Comment: How far away is the Kinect from whatever you are pointing at? Is there lots of light coming from the right side? Is it always like that, no matter where you point the Kinect?

Comment: I tried with different set-ups, the lighting situation hardly matters. There is always a blind spot, no matter where I point the Kinect. Although it seems to be slightly smaller at close range.

Comment: If it's always like that, it does seem like a hardware problem. Contact Microsoft and have them replace your device.